# Microcontrollerembedcode unable to connect to Arduino Yun

Tags: modeling, data-acquisition, microcontroller-kit, arduino

Hi Mathematica enthusiasts,

I am trying to follow this tutorial off Wolfram reference for microcontrollers

[Real Time Data Acquisition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/MicrocontrollerKit/workflow/RealTimeDataAcquisition)

I have an Arduino Yun Rev2 hooked up exactly as it is from the reference link . Everything seems to be connecting and resulting as it should be until I reach...

[image: Problem area]

Which would indicate that I am missing something. I have the circuit hooked up exactly like the reference but Mathematica says

"MicrocontrollerEmbedCode::nopen: Could not open /dev/tty.usbmodem1411."

What does this mean and what can I try to remedy this?

Blockquote

I am attempting to use this to model Simple Harmonic Motion with a spring mass system for a university presentation in April. Any insights or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Most likely the port you have is not /dev/tty.usbmodem1411. If on Mac or Linux see what shows up with `FileNames["/dev/tty.usb*"]`. If on Windows use the device manager.

Comment: Thanks for answering, if it's over wifi, would it show up as a port?

Comment: Unfortunately, uploading over wifi is not yet supported.

Comment: If that's true, then how are they uploading the data in this reference? I'm trying to follow it for a project. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/MicrocontrollerKit/workflow/RealTimeDataAcquisition

Comment: The code is uploaded over a serial port. The sensor data is uploaded over wifi.